# Schematic to PDF

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, schematics, eda

I have 3 schematics files. I want to convert those to PDF format. I don't have the full version of software that can do it. Is there any other way to do the conversion? The free trial version is available but that can only be used to view the schematics file.

edit:

I think the full version of the software is the only way to go.

Comment: Are you trying to circumvent the licence restriction? We can't support you on that.

Comment: VTC as being off-topic. We cannot answer this question without legal issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to copy & paste into some other application that can Save As .pdf, like MS Powerpoint. Screen shots even.

Answer (score 1):

There are several .pdf creator programs that can appear to applications as a printer. These should bypass EasyPC's internal pdf creator, assuming EasyPC can print directly to a normal printer.

I have used Foxit and PDFCreator, and I have "Microsoft Print to PDF" in my printer selection menu (haven't tried that yet...)